# Not getting data values on page load while sending data from Servlet to jsp

Tags: java, ajax, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I am using the bellow ajax for parsing data from servlet to jsp(its working fine)

```
function myfunction() {
    var tableColms = {};
    tableColms.tableName = $('#tableName').val();
    var rowcollection = [];
    $('#tableContent').find('tr').each(function(){
         var row = {};
         row.colName = $(this).find('input[type="text"]').val();
         row.colType = $(this).find('select').val();
         rowcollection.push(row);
     });
     tableColms.tableColomns = rowcollection;
     console.log(tableColms);

     myajax(tableColms);
}

function myajax(jsonParam){
    $.ajax({
        url: "table",
        type: "POST",
        data: "JSON="+JSON.stringify(jsonParam),
        datatype: "application/json",
        success: function(data){
            window.location.href="/CreateDatabase1/getDynamicData.jsp";
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('Exception Occured, '+data);
        }
    });
```

//now i am sending this jsp ajax on the bellow java servlet package

```
com.jwt.servlet;
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

Gson g = new Gson();
tableCls tableDt = g.fromJson(request.getParameter("JSON"), tableCls.class);
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

String table = tableDt.tableName;
request.setAttribute("name", table);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/getDynamicData.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

ERROR__>>>Now on page load i am sending this Request Dispatcher on another jsp there I am not getting any data.

```
<h3> Table name is <%= request.getAttribute ("name") %></h3>
```

I am doing the above project on Eclipse but on The page load i am not able to get any type of data which is coming from (Forward Requestdispatcher).

Comment: `window.location.href="/CreateDatabase1/getDynamicData.jsp";`  this is throwing away any results you had a totally reloading the page

Comment: @ScaryWombat can you please elaborate the above statement.The problem is that i'm not getting any data where i'm throwing it.

Comment: Rather than using the data returned you are re-loading the entire page from scratch